# Remove double quotes from the return of a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, database, postgresql, function

I have the following function in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.translatejson(JSONB, TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
   SELECT ($1->$2)::TEXT
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

When I execute it I receive the values surrounded by double quotes. For example:

`SELECT id, translatejson("title", 'en-US') AS "tname" FROM types."FuelTypes";`

in return I get a table like this

```
-------------------
| id | tname      |
-------------------
| 1  | "gasoline" |
| 2  | "diesel"   |
-------------------
```

The values in the 'title' column are in JSON format: 
{ "en-US":"gasoline", "fr-FR":"essence" }.
How I can omit the double quotes to return just the string of the result?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The `->` operator returns a `json` result. Casting it to `text` leaves it in a json reprsentation.

The `->>` operator returns a `text` result. Use that instead.

```
test=> SELECT '{"car": "going"}'::jsonb -> 'car';
 ?column? 
----------
 "going"
(1 row)

test=> SELECT '{"car": "going"}'::jsonb ->> 'car';
 ?column? 
----------
 going
(1 row)
```

Comment: But it's not clear how to use `->>` if you want to convert array of strings to `text` without quotes `"`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `->>` to convert array of strings to text. Use
`#>>` 
like this 
`'{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}'`. This is from [postgres web docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: @Shersh  you can use :  json_array_elements_text(json)   OR 
 jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb)